# Store created features to PostGIS table via GeoServer does not work: ERROR: Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, openlayers

I'am trying to develop a crowdmapping application for setting points via an OpenLayers Client. These have to be stored via GeoServer to a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension. When I try to save the points I've set before, noting happens. New points do not arrive at PostGIS database and also not to GeoServer. In Google Chrome developer tool mode, I get two messages:

1.) "The specified value "undefined" cannot be parsed, or is out of range."

2.) "Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" "

This is the JavaScript code for creating points. I've added a test layer with styled points where I want to add new points.

```
function create_feature() {
    map.un('click', highlight_mod_attributes);
    map.un('click', highlight);
    document.getElementById("get_info").style.backgroundColor = '';
    map.un('singleclick', getinfo);
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();

    if (modify) {
        map.removeInteraction(modify);
    }
    if (snap_edit) {
        map.removeInteraction(snap_edit);
    }
    document.getElementById("create_feature").style.backgroundColor = 'coral';
    document.getElementById("modify_feature").style.backgroundColor = '';
    document.getElementById("select_feature").style.backgroundColor = '';
   
    //its a geojson-WFS-Layer:

    source_mod = geojson.getSource();
    draw_add = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source_mod,
        type: 'Point'
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw_add);
    
    snap_edit = new ol.interaction.Snap({
        source: source_mod
    });
    map.addInteraction(snap_edit);

    draw_add.on('drawend',
        function(e) {
            
            myFeature = e.feature;
            if (myFeature) {
                var geometry = myFeature.getGeometry();
                var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
                var extent = geometry.getExtent();
                var centroid = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
                featureOverlay.getSource().addFeature(myFeature);

                content1 = '<label for="objektart">Objektart:</label><input type="number"      id="objektart" name="objektart" value=' + myFeature.get('objektart') + '><br><br>';
                content1 += '<label for="pkuid">pkuid (automatisch):</label><input type="number" id="pkuid" name="pkuid" value=' + myFeature.get('pkuid') + '><br><br>';
                content1 += '<label for="melder">Melder (z.B. Name oder Mail):</label><input type="text" id="melder" name="melder" value=' + myFeature.get('melder') + '><br><br>';
                content1 += '<label for="erklaer">Erklärfeld:</label><input type="text" id="erklaer" name="erklaer" value=' + myFeature.get('erklaer') + '><br><br>';
                content1 += '<label for="kurzbeschr">Kurzbeschreibung:</label><input type="text" id="kurzbeschr" name="kurzbeschr" value=' + myFeature.get('kurzbeschr') + '><br><br>';
                content1 += '<button onclick="save_created()" id = "save_created">Save Feature</button>';
                content1 += '<button onclick="cancel_created()" id = "cancel_created">Delete Feature</button>';

                
                content.innerHTML = content1;
                overlay.setPosition(centroid);
             
            }
           
        }, this);

        geojson.getSource().on('addfeature', function() {
          var features = geojson.getSource().getFeatures();
          var length = features.length;
       
    });

}
```

And this is the code for saving created features:

```
function save_created() {

    //store input values
    pkuid = document.getElementById('pkuid').value;
    objektart = document.getElementById('objektart').value;
    melder = document.getElementById('melder').value;
    kurzbeschreibung = document.getElementById('kurzbeschr').value;
    erklaer = document.getElementById('erklaer').value;
    

    
    var coords = myFeature.getGeometry();
    
    var format = new ol.format.GML({
       

    });
    
    var gml3 = format.writeGeometry(coords, {
        
        }

    );
    var url1 = 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wfs';
    var method = 'POST';
    var postData1 =
        '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"\n' +
        'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"\n' +
        'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\n' +
        'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\n' +
        'xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"\n' +
        'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n' +
        'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">\n' +
        '<wfs:Insert>\n' +
        '<crowd:crowdmapping>\n' +
        '<crowd:the_geom>\n' +
        gml3 + '\n' +
        '</crowd:the_geom>\n' +
        '<crowd:pkuid>' + pkuid + '</crowd:pkuid>\n' +
        '<crowd:objektart>' + objektart + '</crowd:objektart>\n' +
        '<crowd:melder>' + melder  + '</crowd:melder>\n' +
        '<crowd:kurzbeschr>' + kurzbeschreibung + '</crowd:kurzbeschr>\n' +
        '<crowd:erklaer>' + erklaer + '</crowd:erklaer>\n' +
        '</crowd:crowdmapping>\n' +
        '</wfs:Insert>\n' +
        '</wfs:Transaction>\n';
   
    var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req1.open("POST", 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wfs', false);
    req1.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0');
    req1.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml');
    req1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req1.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req1.status != 200 && req1.status != 304) {
            alert('HTTP error ' + req1.status);
            return;
        }
        
    }
    if (req1.readyState == 4) return;
    req1.send(postData1);
    
    alert('Feature saved successfully');
    geojson.getSource().refresh();
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();
    featureOverlay.getSource().clear();

}
```

In GeoServer, I activated writing and reading access:

[image]

Does somebody know what to do to save the new point features successfully?

Comment: Look in the log file and see what you have going on. The header issue is a red herring I think. You also need to add the exact XML sent, and the message returned

Comment: I’m new to these issues. Where can I find the log file and the XML sent?

Comment: You can find exact XML sent and the message returned in the browser debugger network section.

Comment: there is a menu item `logs` in the GeoServer left hand menus

Comment: In the XML-File, the Exception says something like that: "<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="request">" and "<ows:ExceptionText>Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter$AdvancedDispatchHttpRequest@3c5756e7</ows:ExceptionText>"

Comment: in the geoserver log file it says: "
ineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 21; Prefix "crowd" for element "crowd:crowdmapping" is not bound."

Answer (score 0):

try this:

replace this:

```
'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">\n' +
```

with this:

```
'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/srbac http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=srbac:mjesta">\n' +
```

... and replace this:

```
 '<crowd:the_geom>\n' +
  gml3 + '\n' +
 '</crowd:the_geom>\n' +
```

with this:

```
'<crowd:the_geom>\n' +
'<gml:MultiPolygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">\n' +
           gml3 + '\n' +
'</gml:MultiPolygon>\n' +
'</crowd:the_geom>\n' +
```